# Express ssl address

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, openssl, port

I am building an express app that will run on my local network. I just started using a self signed certificut and an https server instead of just an http server. Before I implemented https, I could go to my app with `192.168.1.66` (local ip). But after implementing https, I now have to type `https://192.168.1.66:80`, otherwise my browser says "connection was reset" or something similar.

Below is my server creation code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;//is always 80 since I have not 
                                  //set process.end.PORT

var server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(port, function(){
console.log("listening on port 80");
});
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: https is usually served on port 443, not 80... telling the browser to use https on port 80 almost certainly won't work, because the server won't be expecting to get the SSL handshake stuff instead of http request headers.

Comment: I had marked the server to use port 80, which did actually work. However, I've now changed that so that the server runs on 443, and it still doesn't get the web page, even when I specify the protocol and port. :/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Actually this is 100 a programming question. I'm not sure what might have indicated to you that it wasn't. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Silvertail - *"... my browser says 'connection was reset' or something similar."* You didn't bother providing relevant information or an accurate message. But assuming its what I think it is, its a configuration problem. There are other forums more appropriate to learn how Browsers, Servers and TLS work; and how to configure Servers and TLS for browsers.

Comment: @jww. At the time I suspected this was express acting up because I had two servers open with one forwarding to the other (I had never used that configuration before), so you will understand why I posted this here. Also, it might have been more friendly to have first confirmed that this was not a programming problem before directing me somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a firewall issue on linux. I had turned off ufw, but failed to restart afterwards. After restarting and confirming that the firewall was off, it worked fine :)